# Enum, private final String odd behaviour

Tags: java, immutability

I have experienced an odd behaviour. Mainly, if I declare longName and iconPath as private final String, sometimes it happens that these fields values are broken, they have other value than expected.
But if I change the variable type to `private final Pair<String, String> data;` it works fine, ArrayList also does the job. What could be the reason?
I guess the String variable, which is immutable because of final term (although, somehow it does change its value).

```
package package.enums;
import package.MessageUtils;
public enum QuestionType {
    SIMPLE (
            MessageUtils.getBundle("survey.question.type.SIMPLE"),
            "/resources/images/question_default.png"
    ),
    COMPLEX (
            MessageUtils.getBundle("survey.question.type.COMPLEX"),
            "/resources/images/question_default.png"
    )
    // etcetera
    ;

    private final String longName;
    private final String iconPath;
    private QuestionType(String longName, String iconPath) {
        this.longName = longName;
        this.iconPath = iconPath;
    }
    public String getLongName() {
        return longName;
    }
    public String getIconPath() {
        return iconPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you described. I substituted `MessageUtils.getBundle()` by another static method and `getLongName()` and `getIconPath()` seem to be working fine. Could you provide a complete example that will produce the glitch?

Comment: This code might be a little bit misleading, I cannot just post the whole code of the app. But the thing is that JVM put into cache those String values, whereas for Lists it's not the case. That is my suspicion. And I am interested if anyone stepped into such a problem. Constructor takes good variables but in getter you may have different. The problem was solved by changing String to Pair or ArrayList, renaming variables also changes the behaviour to good one.

Answer (score 3):

This looks to me like a "cannot possibly happen" scenario.

The only semi-plausible explanation for a `final` not being initialized correctly is a threading related problem.  However:

- `String` values are definitely immutable and thread-safe,
- there are strong guarantees that `final` fields are thread-safe, and
- this code will be executed as part of the class initialization for the `enum`, and there are guarantees about that too.

In short: it CANNOT be a threading issue in the code you have shown us.

This leaves me with bizarre explanations like:

- something is using nasty reflection to modify the strings,
- something is using nasty reflection to modify the `final` fields, or
- you are not running the code that you think you are; e.g. a build problem or there is some kind of out-of-control "bytecode engineering" going on.

Or ... `MessageUtils.getBundle` is returning the wrong string, under some circumstances that are yet to be determined.

---

> This code might be a little bit misleading, I cannot just post the whole code of the app.

Or ... your real code is different to this code in some significant way.  Please provide a Simple Self Contained Complete Example (SSCCE), or we are unlikely to be able to identify the real problem.

Comment: We work in a team, we worked around that but the story remains unclear. Instead of String fields (or even Lists), we're using `private Class<? extends AbstractDTO> implementingClass;
    private Class<? extends AbstractTransformer> transformerClass;`  and from them `implementingClass.getName() ` is converted to String. Thanks for your propositions. ps. We used to use reflection but it was not the case.

Comment: @SzymonRoziewski - That changes things.  There are more threading related hazards in that scenario ... but I'm not going to speculate unless you show us the real code or an SSCCE.